# Figure Matlab: title desappears

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

When executing:

```
x=1:100;
figure(1)
title('Sobel software execution scalability')
```

I obtain:

[image]

But, when I plot something, executing for example:

```
x=1:100;
figure(1)
title('Sobel software execution scalability')
plot(x)
```

The result is this other one:

[image]

The figure is present but the title is disappeared. What am I doing wrong?

The solution I have found is to add `hold on`:

```
x=1:100;
figure(1)
title('Sobel software execution scalability')
hold on
plot(x)
```

but it sounds really strange. Is it possible that I need to add `hold on` all the time? What if I need to change the figure runtime??

> Note that these few lines were written just for you to replicate the error on your host machine.

Comment: What if you put the title after plot?

Comment: As already suggested, do the plotting first and put the title afterwards. Any call to `plot` will overwrite what was on the figure beforehand, unless `hold on` is used.

Comment: oh,yes. That works fine! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: print the **title** after **plot**. Otherwise, plot will overwrite what was on the figure before.